# How to make script that make some things on SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need to make some things on SQL Server 2008 and I need it on any file or script that I can take it on another computer that has SQL Server 2008

I need this:

1. to add field `F1 (nvarchar)`  and `F2 (bit)` to table `MyTable1`
2. and to make new table `MyTable2`
3. to delete `Table3`

How to combine to one script file ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this, which will work in SQL Server Management Studio:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable1
  ADD F1 NVARCHAR(100)

ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable1
  ADD F2 BIT

GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable2(... define some columns here.......)
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.Table3
GO
```

This uses the `GO` separator which is a keyword for SSMS - but it's **not** a valid SQL keyword (e.g. you cannot run this from code using a SQL Server client library).

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable1 ADD COLUMN F1 NVARCHAR
ALTER TABLE MyTable1 ADD COLUMN F2 BIT
GO

CREATE TABLE MyTable2 (
-- whatever
)
GO

DROP TABLE Table3
GO
```

Then put that in a file and run it with SQLCMD or open it in SSMS.